# Cast in unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, casting, gameobject

This is a piece of Code I found on internet

```
public List<Piece> ramps = new List<Piece>();


1  Gameobject go;
2  go = ramps[visualIndex].gameObject
```

I want to know why the author has put ".gameObject" at the end of the line 2. Is it another type of cast? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Piece` is most likely a custom component inheriting from `MonoBehaviour`.

`ramps[visualIndex]` will retrieve a reference to the `Piece` component.

`go` is declared as a **GameObject**, so calling `ramps[visualIndex].gameObject` will retrieve the gameObject the component is attached to.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component-gameObject.html

There is no cast at all involved here.

Answer (score 1):

Gameobject go; This variable is declared as a GameObject type. You can grab the GameObject associated with any type of script variable. In this case the Piece variable, ramps[visualIndex].